# How Reading From Files and URLs (.plist or .txt)

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdata, nsurl

I need to read a file. plist or. txt from a url

for example.

http://www.nordenmovil.com/BuscadorTopTen/carros.plist

http://www.nordenmovil.com/BuscadorTopTen/texto.txt

```
NSString * path = @ "www.nordenmovil.com/BuscadorTopTen/carros.plist";
     NSError * error;
     NSString * stringFromFileAtPath = [[NSString alloc]
                                       initWithContentsOfFile: path
                                       encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                       error: & error];
     if (stringFromFileAtPath == nil) {
         / / An error occurred
         NSLog (@ "Error reading file at% @ \ n% @",
               path, [error localizedFailureReason]);
     }
     NSLog (@ "% @", stringFromFileAtPath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you use NSURLConnection, you give it the URL, you get back a data object. You then need to convert that object into something that you can deal with - that is, you find iOS classes that can convert that object to the desired format. Suppose the data is an image. Then you would use:

[UIImage imageWithData:];

Its similar for all other objects

Comment: thanks!!

The problem is a bad url format 

http://www.nordenmovil.com/BuscadorTopTen/texto.txt